# Windows batch file find string but don't print

Tags: batch-file, command, windows-scripting, findstr

I'm new to windows batch scripts but have started using the `findstr` command e.g.

```
findstr "test" file.txt
if not errorlevel 1 ( echo Found it!)
```

The code manages to find`test` in `file.txt` but I don't want it to output the line where it finds "test" I just want it to echo `Found it!`

Is this possible with `findstr` or should I be using something else?

Comment: The code in your question cannot give the result you state. It should read `if not errorlevel 1 (echo Found it!)`

Comment: Sorry, I just jotted down a quick example. I've now fixed it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just redirect the output to `nul`.

```
findstr "test" file.txt >nul
if not errorlevel 1 ( echo Found it!)
```

Comment: EDIT - I Fixed the errorlevel logic to match the edited question.

Answer (score 1):

Bali C got the redirection correct, but the OP's original logic was incorrect. Any of the following will work.

```
findstr "test" file.txt >nul
if not errorlevel 1 (echo Found it!)
```

or

```
findstr "test" file.txt >nul
if %errorlevel%==0 (echo Found it!)
```

or my personal favorite

```
findstr "test" file.txt >nul && (echo Found it!)
```